# SSIS: How do you reuse script in a scripting component in another Package?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

OK...I have my first SSIS package that uses a Scripting object. I clicked the Script button and wrote a procedure in the Visual Studio for Applications IDE.

Now I want to reuse this code in another package.

What is the best practice to avoid Control+C, Control V?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting MSDN on reusing **Script Task** that is present in `Control Flow` toolbox. [**Here is the link to MSDN.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx)

> If more than one package uses a script, consider writing a custom task instead of using the Script task. For more information, see Developing a Custom Task.

Quoting MSDN on reusing **Script Component** that is present within `Data Flow Task`. [**Here is the link to MSDN.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx)

> The Script component provides an easy and quick way to include custom functions in a data flow. However, if you plan to reuse the script code in multiple packages, you should consider programming a custom component instead of using the Script component. For more information, see Developing a Custom Data Flow Component.

**Other alternatives that you can look into are**:

1. Create a .NET library with the reusable logic and register the DLL in GAC. Once it is registered in GAC, you can reference the library in Script Task or Script Component. [**Here is a link**](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html) that describes about this.
2. You can also have a look at the third-party components [**Script Task Plus**](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/script-task) and [**Script Component Plus**](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/script-component) developed by CozyRoc.

Hope that helps.